# mariadb as docker container - corrupted startup on host mount binding

Tags: docker, encryption, phpmyadmin, mariadb, mounted-volumes

i want to run latest mariadb:10.4.8 as docker container with its data folder persisted as host mount.

This is my docker-compose.yaml

```
database:
mem_limit: 1073741824
image: mariadb:stable
environment:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: mydata
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: '123456'
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '12345678'
  MYSQL_USER: mydata
  MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
stdin_open: true
volumes:
- /opt/mydata/keys/keyfile.key:/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key
- /opt/mydata/keys/keyfile.enc:/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc
- /opt/mydata/database:/var/lib/mysql
- /opt/mydata/logs:/var/log/mysql
tty: true
cpu_shares: 512
command:
- --max-allowed-packet=100M
- --character-set-server=utf8mb4
- --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
- --net-write-timeout=300
- --net-read-timeout=300
- --log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log
- --plugin-load-add=file_key_management
- --file-key-management-filename=/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc
- --file-key-management-filekey=FILE:/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key
- --file-key-management-encryption-algorithm=AES_CTR
- --innodb-encrypt-log=ON
- --innodb-encrypt-tables=FORCE
labels:
  io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
```

Problem is the 'mydata' user is not created anymore - i can't login as root or mydata.
I don't see any 'mydata' folder under "/opt/mydata/database".
Connection with phpmadmin results in:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

It seems if this tasks succeeds the first time - no problem occurs but if it doesn't i can try as often as i want - it won't work.

When i spin this service up - the first mariadb container dies suddenly then anotherone gets started.

This runs on a fully updated Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Host.

The setup is pretty much the same everytime because our Container etc. get provisioned with terraform against Rancher Container Orchestrtion.

I tried on different docker versions 18.06 and 18.09 CE.

I'm getting short on ideas right now, any ideas what could be the case here ?

Comment: did you remember the password when you create it first time? try with that password. seems like your current password is different

Comment: thx but this is no password related problem i tried that already

Comment: So far i tried a lot here but nothing helped.
mariadb remains in a state where i can't login locally with the root user.
Also a "test" folder is created in "/var/lib/mysql" with a single file db.opt in it and nothing else.

Comment: one thin that i can suggest but I am not sure it will work or not. create a fresh container with mount location, once login verfied then try to copy db files one by one and check if it able to access

Comment: Just for reference: may we where hitting https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/issues/262 an now tried to downgrad to 10.3.17 and/or use MYSQL_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading "github.com/docker-library/mariadb/issues/262" i dowgraded to 10.3.16.
Creating new mariadb works reliably with that version.
10.3.17, 10.3.18 and 10.4.8 had all the above mentioned issues.

Comment: Note this is now corrected with 10.1.46, 10.2.23, 10.3.24, 10.4.14, 10.5.5 and all 10.6+ versions